# Deploying C# program with MYSQL database usage

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Hi all
I was given assignment by the database teacher and i had to make UI and interface that with MYSQL .

I did it by installing mysql connector. Now the problem is that i donot know that he has it on his computer or not.I am sure he has installed MYSQL ,SQLYOG and SQL workbench on his system but no visual studio.

if i give him Visual Studio Solution that is not going to work so i planned to make setup Project but there was a confusion that will it work at his system?

any idea how this could be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of referencing the MySQL connector from the GAC, create a folder called references in the source code folder, copy the connector there, remove the refence to it from the gac and re-add the reference from your local folder, build, test...

Then close Visual Studio and zip the folder with source code and reference subfolder and send it to him by email.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Copy Local** property of the MySQL reference(s) to **true**.

For example, if your project contains a reference to **MySql.Data** then right-click it and select Properties. In the Properties window you will see the **Copy Local** property. Simply set it to be **true**. Then instead of searching the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) of the target machine for the MySql.Data.dll your executable will look for it in the same directory as it is located.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details on the Copy Local property.